# Roads vs streets

Tags: simcity-4

I'm currently reading the [SIM CITY 4 GUIDE: VERSION 2, by thy451](http://www.gamefaqs.com/pc/561176-simcity-4/faqs/21501) 
And found this strange: mentioned, that roads have more capacity, than streets, but according to the table in the same chapter, streets have more capacity. Is it a bug in table?

```
A1.04.1: Options: Transport Types

1) Road Vehicle Transport: Streets, Road and Highway
This is the most basic form of transportation around. Streets have a very 
much smaller capacity about a tenth than roads while highway offers about 
four times more capacity than a road. They too have differing speeds with 
the streets being the lowest and the highway being the highest. Even buses 
add to the traffic of the roads.

4) Cost and Capacity

Table A1.04.2: Transport
$C: Cost to build / In the case of medium and large airports, this figure 
    represents the upgrade cost.
$M: Monthly maintenance cost
CA: Capacity
P: Passenger
G: Goods in tons
%: Treat this as a percentage when contrasted with the rest in that category

--------------------------------------
Structure         | $C  | $M  | CA   |
--------------------------------------
Cars              |                  |
--------------------------------------
Roads             | 10  | 0.10|100%  |
Streets           | 5   | 0.05|1000% |
Bus Stops         | 150 | 5   |1000P |
High way          | 600 | 1   |4000% |
Cloverleaf        | 3000| 26  |4000% |
--------------------------------------
```

Comment: I think it's just a typo. We know that both intuitively and from experience streets certainly do not have more capacity than roads, far less than 10x the capacity. You should probably email the author of the guide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's a bug in the table. Roads are higher capacity that streets. Streets are mostly meant to provide access through smaller-traffic areas where roads are better for connecting such areas together.

Answer (score 2):

[This article here](http://www.gamefaqs.com/pc/561176-simcity-4/faqs/23133) details roads vs streets:

Now, each tile of street and roads takes a certain amount of time to traverse:

> ```
>         Streets   Roads   Highways
> Cars    50 sec    30 sec  12 sec
> Busses  30 sec    20 sec  10 sec
> ```

They also have set limits of sims that can pass per cycle:

> ```
>           Streets   Roads   Highways
> Capacity  100       1000    4000
> ```

They also have multipliers on the time passed depending how busy they are:

> ```
> Road Capacity   Speed Multiplier
> 101%-200%:      -1% thru -35%
> 201%+:          -36% thru -70%
> Intersection:   -30% (assuming both directions are used, otherwise the sims will
>                 just run the red lights and stop signs as a matter of course.
>                 For the two tiles leading up to the intersection, the delay
>                 diminishes by 10%.
> ```

The commute works in adding up the total travel times of all the tiles used for a trip, taking into account multipliers for traffic intensity and busy intersections. The total is then rounded up to the nearest integer in minutes, and put in average with the rest of the totals that were drawn in that cycle.

Busses are preferable to cars in the sims' eyes because they are actually faster than cars but busses still use the roads and are counted by number of sims, (hence no indication of individual bus capacity) which explains why they don't lower traffic, only commute times. Subways are the same way, except they don't use the roads, so they *can* lower traffic.